# Grafana alert for memory leaks in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, grafana

We have a Spring boot service and we use Actuator/Prometheus/Grafana for monitoring. The default metrics are available and JVM memory metrics can be used for visualizing memory usage. Simple Grafana alert can be defined on jvm_memory_used_bytes metric to detect memory spikes. But the memory spikes can be expected behavior in case of heavy load on the service and if there is no memory leak the Garbage Collector will release the memory. Probably better approach would be to detect gradually increasing average memory usage over longer period, and define an alert to be fired over a certain threshold. Any idea for PromQL query for gradual increase of the average value of jvm_memory_used_bytes metric, please?